# How can I add an object to an entity class object?

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine

```
$data = $this->em->getRepository(data::class)->findAll();
```

I want to add an object to $data:

```
foreach($table as &$arr){
    if($arr->getId() == "55"){
      $arr->{'color'} = 'blue';
    }
  }
```

This is how my object looks created from data:

```
Documents {#1548 ▼
  -id: 55
  -name: "sky"
  +"color": "blue"
}
```

Is it possible to transform the `color` object into the same format then `name`? So that it looks like this:

```
Documents {#1548 ▼
  -id: 55
  -name: "sky"
  -color: "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**color** is not an object but an attribute of an object.

You just have to add it into your class file like this example:

```
Class Documents {
   protected $id;
   protected $name;
   public $color;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this is the problem, that is not flexible. I need a flexible solution, that I can add it on the controller flexible. In some cases I have to add color, in another case I need to add profession etc.

Comment: So you ve to do this `$arr->color = 'blue';`.
But it is not a good way !

Comment: there is no other way?